# Is there a audio wireless home system

Tags: wireless, sound-system

I would like to set up a wireless audio set up for my home, i have 3 room in which i would like to have speakers so i could listen to music. I would like these speakers to be able to connect wirelessly to my pc and android phone. I will have power to supply the speakers. 
 All i could find are some bluetooth systems that could support a maximum of 2 speakers. But on one hand i need three and on the other hand my apartments walls are reinforced concrete so i don't think bluetooth is the way to go.

Comment: Will all the speakers be playing audio at the same time? Will they be playing the same audio, or do you need support for multiple streams eg. play stream 1 in bedroom 1, steam 2 in bedroom 2?

Comment: they will have the same stream source pc or phone

Comment: I haven't been able to find much on this but a potential solution could be to use NFC tags near the doorway to each room, and program each one to connect your phone to that room's bluetooth speaker. So as you go into each area while playing music on the phone, you swipe it and it'll change settings. For the PC you could just get multiple bluetooth adapters and set a windows shortcut to cycle them, but you may run into signal issues there. I wish I could be of more help but everything I can find is on the level of expensive smart home systems with hardware installation requirements.

Comment: @jcam3 what kind of hardware? I am willing to install some kind of hi-fi radio or wi-fi transmitter/receiver set up .

Comment: Could i do it with something similar to a FM car transmitter the ones that have bluetooth on them. And on each speaker i would have a mini radio receiver. The Fm transmitter would connect to the speakers and i would connect to the Fm transmitter with trough bluetooth with either my phone or my PC. Would this be doable?